# why does if(function_name()) not work?

Tags: php

Hey guys really quick question, I have a simple test that I was doing to prove a point and it does not work like I expected but I am not sure why it does not work.

```
function test(){
    echo 'test';
}

if (test()){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

That was my test. 'ok' is not echoed and I am not sure why. I was testing this because my real code is calling a class method and is also not working.

```
if($database->addNewUser($user, md5($pass), $userfile, $email, $age)){
    return 0;  //New user added succesfully
}
```

The method addNewUser executes and does what it should, but the return 0; does not. Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would return 0 on success...

Comment: returning 0 is a common practice in many cases.  It basically means there was no error where a number would indicate an error code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your test function is ECHOING not returning..

```
function test(){
   return true; // what to send back
}

if (test()){ // true was sent back, so.
    echo 'ok';
}
```

will echo 'ok'.

look at $database->addNewUser() - what's it *returning* ?

Comment: I think he meant to `return 'test';`, to prove that non-empty strings evaluate to true.

Comment: thanks dan appreciate it, i added return true to make the function true and it evaluates correctly now

Comment: @blueraja - yeah, i thought so too but true/false seemed a better teaching aid. Perhaps evaluating strings is part 2 of his journey :)

Comment: when you say evaluating strings, I googled it and got the function eval. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: lol no - evaluating, as in evaluating the condition.. more english definition then programatic definition ;) Because return "text"; would still "evaluate" as true. return 45; would evaluate as true;

Comment: @Scarface: it means that `if('test') { echo 'ok'; }` will echo "ok"

Comment: ooo lol thanks guys, I hate coming off as so amateur but I am always learning lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `test()` doesn't return any value. PHP treats this absence of a value as false, so the body of the `if` block is never executed.

With your full example, the problem is either than `addNewUser` doesn't return a value, or it's returning a false value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something to indicate success.  Either of these would work:

```
function test(){
    echo 'test';
    return TRUE;
}
```

or, less desirable, but should still work:

```
function test(){
    echo 'test';
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return true.  Why would you expect 'ok' to be echoed?

Comment: I did not know that was the problem, that is why I was asking lol.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't meaning to be snarky.  I was thinking there was more to it.

Comment: Snarkyness on stackoverflow...never.

Answer (score 0):

Your `test()` function does not `return` a value - I would not expect this to work. Try returning something from it, such as `TRUE`.